# java Socket or DatagramSocket for connecting to a NNTP server

Tags: java, sockets, datagram

Hay Guys, i want to write a simple NNTP client, which can connect to a server, send AUTHINFO details, and use GROUP and BODY to join a group and retreive posts.

I had a discussion with a couple of guys in here and they suggested using dataGramSockets and datGramPackets.

Could anyone provide a simple script to do these explaining how each command works and why use DataGram Sockets over the tradtional Socket? I used Socket and was able to connect to my server, but i hadn't a clue how to use getInputStream() and getOutputStream() to send/receive data to the server.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't NNTP a TCP-based protocol ? I don't think datagrams would be appropriate here. See the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3977) for further info re. using this protocol.

I see that Apache Commons Net offer [an NNTP package](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/nntp/package-tree.html), which may be of use.

> NNTPClient encapsulates all the
> functionality necessary to post and
> retrieve articles from an NNTP server.
> As with all classes derived from
> SocketClient, you must first connect
> to the server with connect  before
> doing anything, and finally
> disconnect()  after you're completely
> finished interacting with the server.
> Remember that the isAllowedToPost()
> method is defined in NNTP.

I'd avoid using raw sockets if someone has already done this hard work.

Comment: How would i include this package in a android application?

Comment: Sorry. I'm not au fait with Android, so I can't really advise on that specifically.

Comment: Managed to import it, but when i run nntp.connect(). It crashes the app.